# Why sets of nonzero measure contain almost all the point from Borel-cantelli Leems?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas, measurable-sets

The question referred from this discussion [Borel-Cantelli Lemma "Corollary" in Royden and Fitzpatrick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739172/borel-cantelli-lemma-corollary-in-royden-and-fitzpatrick#:~:text=The%20Borel-Cantelli%20lemma%20says,the%20event%20E%20is%20zero.&text=For%20its%20significance%2C%20it%20is,events%20occurring%20together%20is%20zero.)

I understand the proof of the Leems.But i still don't get "Then almost all x ∈ R belong to at most finitely many of the E_Ks"? i understood that if x belongs to infinitely E_k then the set contain all such x has measure 0 but how it implies finitely many x's belongs to that set? or infinitely many x ∈ R belong to at most finitely many of the Ek's? how i can get a contradiction?

THanks in advance for the help.

Comment: actually i think this is a sort of duplicate of my eponymous/namesake question because even though the answer says 'check this!', the answerer actually elaborates a little more in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

Let $E= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k$.  Note that $x \in E$ if and only if $x$ belongs to infinitely many of the $E_k$.

The Borel-Cantelli lemma says that if $\sum m(E_k) < \infty$, then $m(E) = 0$.  That is to say, almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ *do not* belong to $E$.  So this means that almost all $x$ have the property that $x$ does not belong to infinitely many of the $E_k$, which is to say that each such $x$ belongs to only finitely many of the $E_k$.

Note that nothing in the statement is talking about "infinitely many $x$" or "finitely many $x$".  You seem to have got that part mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nate. I am still want to clarify why  ∑m(Ek)<∞, then m(E)=0 implies almost all x∈R do not belong to E? If it because s set with positive measure should contain more element than set of measure 0?. Thanks again. I'm typing from mobile. Do please pardon any typing issue. Thanks

Comment: That's just the definition of the phrase "almost all" - that it's true for every $x$ except those in some set of measure zero.  The terminology is just meant to reinforce the informal idea that sets of measure zero are very small.

Comment: actually i think this is a sort of duplicate of my eponymous/namesake question because even though the answer says 'check this!', the answerer actually elaborates a little more in the comments?